# Detect close tag in DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm using the DOM parser in JAVA to read a XML file. How do I detect when element node closes(ends) ?

Example XML:

```
<student><eng>90</eng><mat>90</mat><science>90</science></student>
<student><mat>90</mat><eng>90</eng></student>
```

I know there is endElement in SAX parser. Is there similar or alternative to find it?

I want to compute once student node closes.

Answer (score 0):

Closing tags are part of the tag itself. They only exist in the markup form to distinguish whether the next tag is a child element or a sibling. In the DOM that's not needed because the nodes are already linked in a tree, they know which one is a sibling and which is a child.

In other words, they are merely an encoding artifact, not independent constructs. Therefore DOM-parsing does not preserve them.

Since SAX is not a DOM parser, it does not create object conforming to the Document Object Model, it does things differently.

Comment: I suspect that there is no problem. try actually coding something with the DOM, then show us what code does not work.